Unity HDRP, my Canvas becomes smaller on the scene screen
This is the first time I've used HDRP, and when I try to add a canvas, I get something weird.
When the canvas is in the scene screen, if I touch the canvas or a child object of the canvas, the canvas becomes smaller than its normal size and I can't see it when I switch to the game screen.
But there is such a strangeness that when I switch to the scene on the game screen, it returns to normal again.
When I select the text on the game screen and try to change its position, it shrinks again.
Normal
When i click canvas or any children of canvas
Canvas settings
What is causing this? Are my settings wrong or something else?
Thanks.
.

Can you show your Game View? The Camera and thereby the Screenspace Overlap Canvas always adopts the size of the current Game View (= display screen) ... or did you double click and it didn't actually change size but rather just zoom out?

It's in the right place on the game screen.
https://imgur.com/a/1xCzmcd
I don't know how to add a picture to the comment, sorry. That's why I left an imgur link.
And thank you for your reply.
https://imgur.com/a/CKBTytB
When I'm on the game screen, when I look at the size of the canvas in the inspector, it turns up weird numbers like this.
